# Hide/block page elements from RSS feed

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed

I sometimes add a "related posts"-type footer to posts on my Wordpress blog. Just manually, per post, rather than automated.

The footer of course appears in my blog's RSS feed, and I'd like to know if it is possible to hide it, or block it, or prevent it from appearing in the feed. I've tried enclosing the footer in a div, and then using a feed-styling plugin to hide or not display that div, but it hasn't worked.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields), which will not be added to your feed. You can use a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-fields/), if you're not comfortable with coding.