# Hide Gutenberg's Pullquote Block from RSS Feed in Wordpress

Tags: php, rss, filtering, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

**Brief explanation of our need:** When we use a pullquote in a post we want it filtered out/hidden from the RSS feed, while at the same time continuing to show up in the content when viewing the post on the website.

**Fuller explanation of our need:** A pullquote highlights a specific piece of content from an article/page/post by repeating the content and bringing it slightly outside of the flow of the article/page/post content. This works well when using CSS, because it makes it clear that it is not to be read in the flow of the article's content, but to highlight a good sentence or two. Pullquotes are repeated content. However, in an RSS feed, the repeated content is awkward. We'd like to automatically filter out all pullquotes from our blog content on RSS feeds, while keeping it in the post content for frontend viewing.

****What have I tried?****

- I've tried this plugin and it didn't work: https://wordpress.org/plugins/content-visibility-rss-feed/
- I've read this, but don't know how to make it work for filtering pullquotes: [Remove certain elements from an RSS feed such as short codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39072884/remove-certain-elements-from-an-rss-feed-such-as-short-codes)
- I've read this, and while he outlines the problem well, we need a PHP solution and not a JS solution: https://css-tricks.com/better-pull-quotes/
- I've read this stack overflow post, but we don't want to use custom fields: [Hide/block page elements from RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5801545/hide-block-page-elements-from-rss-feed)

Answer (score 0):

A friend provided this code that I've tested, and it works well.

```
// Remove all Gutenberg pull quote blocks from feeds
function theme_filter_pull_quotes( $content ) {
    return preg_replace('#<figure class="wp-block-pullquote(.*?)</figure>#', '', $content );
}
add_filter('the_content_feed', 'theme_filter_pull_quotes');
```

As you can see, the opening  tag is not closed because depending upon your block settings, Wordpress may add other classes which would not match the pattern. Leaving the tag opened allows any additional classes to be included. It seems wp-block-quote is always the first class.